# Redirect logged in user from log in page

Tags: php, redirect, mysqli, error-handling, header

Looked around at other posts but still struggling. Currently got a CRM system going. User starts off in /index.php.

```
<?php
include_once'header.php';   
?>

<section class="main-container">
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <h2>Motoko</h2>

    <?php   

        if (isset($_GET["msg"]) && $_GET["msg"] == 'failed') {
        echo "Incorrect Username/Password";
        } 
        else { if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd))
        echo "You are not logged in";
            }                   
    ?>
</div>
</section>
<?php
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Whereby /header.php contains:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Motoko</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<header> 
<nav>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>   
        </ul>
        <div class="nav-login">
            <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])){
                echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
                </form>';
                } else {
                echo '<form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST"> 
                <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/e-mail">
                <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button> 
                </form>';

                echo '<form action="signup.php" method="POST"> 
                <button type="submit">Sign up</button> 
                </form>';

                echo '<form action="reset.php" method="POST"> 
                <button type="submit">Forgot your Password?</button> 
                </form>';

                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

I need to add something like if (isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) header("Location: to where you would be redirected when you log in --> view.php)

I'm not sure where the statement should go. And if there is any other syntax that needs to be added.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this code will help you.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['u_uid']))
    echo ('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.replace("http://yoursite.com/yourpath.php");</script>');
```

Comment: Cheers mate. I've already found a solution, but appreciate your help :)